# How to handle flag-worthy answers in old questions?

Tags: discussion, flags

When reading older questions (>3-4 years as of 2015), I often come across chatty answers that would maybe appropriate in a forum thread, but not for SO Q&A format.

I was wondering if I should still flag answers like that since I feel that my flags on such answers often get declined or disputed. The most recent example is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3421055/368354) one, which was declined with "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it". It even has one of those auto-generated comments from the low quality review queue.

Comment: Which flag did you use? If it was NAA it was probably declined because it's an attempt to answer.

Comment: What else? It's neither spam nor rude, it's just a comment posted as answer.

Comment: That example is a very poor answer indeed. I also flagged it. I would still apply flags to old questions as you encounter them. It helps to keep SO clean of "noise".

Comment: @Lennart FYI, my flag as NAA got tagged as helpful and the answer has been deleted. That's interesting...